# AutoMapper mapping two concrete classes that share an interface

Tags: c#, interface, automapper, automapper-2

I have an interface that describes two objects.  One is a DAO, the other is a BO.  So, here's what it looks like:

```
public interface IOrder ...

public class OrderDAO : IOrder ...

public class OrderBO : IOrder ...
```

And I would like to map OrderDAO to OrderBO.  My original line of thought was that I could simply map interface to interface and supply both concrete objects, like so:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IOrder, IOrder>(myOrderDAO, myOrderBO);
```

However, this did not work out-of-the-box.  I still had to create a map in order to get the data from myOrderDAO to myOrderBO.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IOrder, IOrder>();
```

I'm not sure that makes a lot of sense to me and I feel like I'm "doing it wrong", as it were.  So my question is two-fold.

1. What is the best way to map in the above scenario?
2. Why would I need to create a map for the same interface?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. this is a good way to map. However if you want to reduce number of CreateMap calls, create a method that would create all maps and then call it once per application domain. for example from some static constructor or another app start event. see [how they recommend it in their Get Started](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)
2. even it is for the same interface there still should be a map, I guess. on the bright side it makes your life easier, you do not have to create maps like  and a lot more. It could be an optimization though.